# How to understand the _dual_coef_ parameter in sklearn's kernel svm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

I have a small kernel svm code.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np  

# Load the IRIS dataset for demonstration
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Train-test split
X_train, y_train = X[:140], y[:140]
X_test, y_test = X[140:], y[140:]

print(X.shape, X_train.shape, X_test.shape) # prints (150, 4) (140, 4) (10, 4)

# Fit a rbf kernel SVM
gamma = 0.7
svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, C=64, decision_function_shape='ovo')
# svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, C=64, probability=True, decision_function_shape='ovo')
# svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, C=64)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(svc.score(X_test, y_test))

# Get prediction for a point X_test using train SVM, svc
def get_pred(svc, X_test):

    def RBF(x,z,gamma,axis=None):
        return np.exp((-gamma*np.linalg.norm(x-z, axis=axis)**2))

    A = []
    # Loop over all suport vectors to calculate K(Xi, X_test), for Xi belongs to the set of support vectors
    for x in svc.support_vectors_:
        # A.append(RBF(x, X_test, svc._gamma))
        A.append(RBF(x, X_test, gamma))
    A = np.array(A)

    return (np.sum(svc._dual_coef_*A)+svc.intercept_)


for i in range(X_test.shape[0]):
    print(get_pred(svc, X_test[i]))
    print(svc.decision_function([X_test[i]])) # The output should same
```

I want to understand the role of the `_dual_coef_` parameter in svm, so I implemented a prediction function `get_pred` of svm myself.

According to the mathematical expression of svm [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-mathematical-formulation).

[image: math]

> These parameters can be accessed through the attributes **dual_coef_** which holds the product **$y_i \alpha_i$**, support_vectors_ which holds the support vectors, and intercept_ which holds the independent term $b$

$$
\sum_{i\in SV}y_i \alpha_i K(x, x_i) + b
$$

```
 = sum(_dual_coef_ * K) + intercepte_
```

But the output of the function I implemented is different from the function that comes with svm.

```
(150, 4) (140, 4) (10, 4)
1.0
[-4.24105215 -4.38979215 -3.52427244]
[[-0.42115154 -1.06817962 -2.36560357]]
[-2.34091311 -2.48965311 -1.6241334 ]
[[-0.61615543 -0.86736268 -0.47127757]]
[-4.34859785 -4.49733785 -3.63181814]
[[-0.86662754 -1.14637099 -1.94948189]]
[-4.14797518 -4.29671518 -3.43119547]
[[-0.32438219 -1.12869709 -2.30877848]]
[-3.80505008 -3.95379007 -3.08827037]
[[-0.3341635  -1.03315401 -2.05161515]]
[-3.83632958 -3.98506957 -3.11954987]
[[-0.62920059 -0.97474828 -1.84626328]]
[-3.94804683 -4.09678683 -3.23126712]
[[-0.90348467 -1.04135143 -1.61709331]]
[-4.24990319 -4.39864319 -3.53312348]
[[-0.83485694 -1.07466796 -1.95426087]]
[-3.39840443 -3.54714443 -2.68162472]
[[-0.52530703 -0.9980642  -1.48891578]]
[-3.03105705 -3.17979705 -2.31427734]
[[-0.93796146 -1.09834078 -0.60863738]]
```

How can I understand this parameter `_dual_coef_`, or put another way, how can I implement the prediction function of the kernel svm myself?

This problem has been bugging me for weeks.

---

the value `_dual_coef_` and `dual_coef_` is same.

```
print(svc.dual_coef_)
print(svc._dual_coef_)
```

output

```
[[ 0.00000000e+00  2.89411525e-01  6.42572850e-01  3.49005828e-01
   4.89527283e-01  8.68509232e-01  1.70309469e-02 -6.31981548e-01
  -0.00000000e+00 -2.24785323e-01 -2.22867415e-01 -1.54772961e-01
  -1.23240646e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -2.23517902e-01
  -2.78405788e-01 -3.61957209e-02 -7.60290361e-01 -3.84061473e-01
  -5.84800982e-01 -1.58444536e-01 -1.38767496e-01 -1.03491055e-01
  -5.16469524e-01 -2.61912890e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00
  -1.83395105e-01 -4.11383501e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -1.78565851e-01
  -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.18138228e-02  3.34311828e-01  7.33944808e-01  4.55819619e-01
   3.83152925e-01  9.40418724e-01  4.18306844e-02  0.00000000e+00
   3.18472098e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   6.40000000e+01  5.54398171e+01  2.84918781e+01  6.40000000e+01
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00
  -3.97780557e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -2.19815863e-01
  -7.62771179e-01 -3.35105127e+01 -5.64451371e+00 -3.65670112e+01
  -2.59917431e+00 -5.61374655e-01 -6.40000000e+01 -7.86608975e-01
  -6.40000000e+01 -2.48682797e+00]]
[[ 0.00000000e+00  2.89411525e-01  6.42572850e-01  3.49005828e-01
   4.89527283e-01  8.68509232e-01  1.70309469e-02 -6.31981548e-01
  -0.00000000e+00 -2.24785323e-01 -2.22867415e-01 -1.54772961e-01
  -1.23240646e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -2.23517902e-01
  -2.78405788e-01 -3.61957209e-02 -7.60290361e-01 -3.84061473e-01
  -5.84800982e-01 -1.58444536e-01 -1.38767496e-01 -1.03491055e-01
  -5.16469524e-01 -2.61912890e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00
  -1.83395105e-01 -4.11383501e-01 -0.00000000e+00 -1.78565851e-01
  -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00]
 [ 3.18138228e-02  3.34311828e-01  7.33944808e-01  4.55819619e-01
   3.83152925e-01  9.40418724e-01  4.18306844e-02  0.00000000e+00
   3.18472098e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   6.40000000e+01  5.54398171e+01  2.84918781e+01  6.40000000e+01
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00
  -3.97780557e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00 -2.19815863e-01
  -7.62771179e-01 -3.35105127e+01 -5.64451371e+00 -3.65670112e+01
  -2.59917431e+00 -5.61374655e-01 -6.40000000e+01 -7.86608975e-01
  -6.40000000e+01 -2.48682797e+00]]
```

Comment: The documentation mentiones `dual_coef_`, while `_dual_coef_` is by convention a “private” attribute. Are you sure you are using the correct attribute?

Comment: @Tim Yes, I know the `_dual_coef_` value is private, but its value is the same as `dual_coef_`, you can print two values to check. I changed the value of `_dual_coef_` to `dual_coef_` in the code, and the final output is still the same